# Renaming multiple files to a random string renames only one file

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, random

Trying to rename files to a random string. I took some code from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837061/a-random-string-generator-in-a-bash-script-isnt-respecting-the-number-of-given) in order to generate a random string of characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=( {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} )

function rand_string {
    local c=$1 ret=
    while((c--)); do
        ret+=${chars[$((RANDOM%${#chars[@]}))]}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ret"
}

output=$(rand_string 10)
```

For practice I made a directory at `$HOME/practice` with a few plain text files.

```
/Users/me/practice/testfile1.txt
/Users/me/practice/testfile2.txt
/Users/me/practice/testfile3.txt
```

When trying to rename these files a random string, instead of getting 3 random names, I am instead left with 1 file renamed to a random string.

```
for file in $HOME/practice/*
do
    mv "$file" $HOME/practice/"$output" 
done

#result
/Users/me/practice/i6TP3wiMDD
```

Replacing `mv "$file" ~/practice/"$output"` with `echo "$file" "$output"` shows me that the random string is being repeated after every file instead of generating a new random string for every file.

```
/Users/me/practice/testfile1.txt i6TP3wiMDD
/Users/me/practice/testfile2.txt i6TP3wiMDD
/Users/me/practice/testfile3.txt i6TP3wiMDD
```

My question is two part:

1. Why is only 1 file being renamed?
2. How can I generate a new random string for each file being renamed?

I will also say that the above random character script is above my current understanding. I know that it works for generating random characters. But the inner workings of it are still somewhat unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are generating only instance of the random value and storing it in the `output` variable and using the same to rename all the files in the loop. See the shell script expansion which comes when run with the `set -x` option after the defining the she-bang(`#!/bin/bash`).

```
+++ rand_string 10
+++ local c=10 ret=
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=O
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=k
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=H
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=Q
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=1
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=u
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=9
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=4
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=c
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=C
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ printf '%s\n' OkHQ1u94cC     # <--- See the same random file-names used throughout the files
++ output=OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv 1.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv 2.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv 5000.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv 5100.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv abc.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv file.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv final.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv ini1.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv ini2.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv listing.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv names.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv parameters.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv properties.txt OkHQ1u94cC
++ for file in '*.txt'
++ mv result.txt OkHQ1u94cC
```

The above is with my sample data. The best way is to fix the for loop in function rename by calling the function at time of expansion. Like below

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $HOME/practice/*
do
    mv "$file" $HOME/practice/"$(rand_string 10)"   # <-- Here the random string length can be controlled as you need.
done
```

Now with the above fix, you can see my script of actual renaming of my `.csv` files expanded as

```
+++ rand_string 10
+++ local c=10 ret=
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=7
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=j
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=U
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=K
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=l
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=V
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=l
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=6
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=8
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=8
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ printf '%s\n' 7jUKlVl688
++ output=7jUKlVl688
++ for file in '*.csv'
+++ rand_string 10
+++ local c=10 ret=
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=N
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=B
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=O
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=p
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=j
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=5
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=T
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=b
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=S
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=R
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ printf '%s\n' NBOpj5TbSR
++ mv 1.csv NBOpj5TbSR                  # <- Unique file names generated.
+++ rand_string 10
+++ local c=10 ret=
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=N
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=R
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=Y
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=C
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=C
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=X
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=L
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=0
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=e
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ ret+=l
+++ (( c-- ))
+++ printf '%s\n' NRYCCXL0el
++ mv 2.csv NRYCCXL0el                    # <- Unique file names generated.
```