# Using positional parameters in place of if statements

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

I'm trying to better understand how to write bash scripts using positional parameters as arguments to the script. Specifically I want to understand how to make a script as user friendly as possible, capable of handling multiple arguments from any position. Much in that `ls -lst` is the same as `ls -stl`. I decided to attempt a password generator. I'm not very familiar with writing scripts that take arguments. After a while I just decided to do the whole thing using `if` statements.

**Note: to give credit where credit is due, the `rand_string` function in the script below came directly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23837814/5904552).**

```
#!/bin/bash

## grep -v '##' will remove all the comments if you're so inclined :)
usage(){
echo "usage: $0 [n][-c]||[-h]"  
}

## Character set used to create random strings 
chars=( {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} \! \" \# \$  \% \& \( \) \* \+ \, \- \. \/ \: \; \< \= \> \? \@ \[ \] \^ \_ \` \{ \| \} \~ \\ )

## Create random string from character set
rand_string() { 
    local c=$1 ret=
    while((c--)); do
        ret+=${chars[$((RANDOM%${#chars[@]}))]}; done
    printf '%s\n' "$ret"
}

## get a random number between 14-50
length() {
    python -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(14,50)"
}

## regular expression to test for valid numbers
re='^[0-9]+$'

## if no options specified 
## create a random string of charcters
## of a random length between 14-50 characters
## display password on screen and exit
if [ ! "$1" ]; then
    set - "$(length)"
    password="$(rand_string "$1")"
    echo "$password"
    exit
fi

## if option 1 or option 2 is -h or -help
## display usage and exit
if [[ "$1" == -h || "$1" == -help || "$2" == -h || "$2" == -help ]]; then
    usage
    exit
fi

## if more than 2 options
## exit with error code 1
if [[ $# -gt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid number of options specified"
    usage
    exit 1
fi
## if exactly 2 options
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    ## test if option 1 is a number
    ## if option 1 is NOT a number 
    if [[ ! "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
        ## test if option 1 is -c or -copy
        if [[ "$1" == -c || "$1" == -copy ]]; then
            ## if option 1 is -c or -copy
            ## test if option 2 is a number
            ## if 2 is a number and 1 is -c or -copy 
            ## execute the command
            if [[ "$2" =~ $re ]]; then
                set - "$(length)"
                rand_string "$1" | pbcopy
                echo "Password copied to clipboard"
                exit
            ## if option 1 is -c or -copy
            ## but option 2 is NOT a number
            ## exit script with error code 1
            elif [[ ! "$2" =~ $re ]]; then
                echo "Unrecognized option \"$2\""
                usage
                exit 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Unrecognized option \"$1\""
            exit 1
        fi
    ## if option 1 is a number
    elif [[ "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
        ## and option 2 is -c or -copy
        ## execute the command
        if [[ "$2" == -c || "$2" == -copy ]]; then
            rand_string "$1" | pbcopy
            echo "Password copied to clipboard"
            exit
        ## if option 1 is a number 
        ## but option 2 is not -c or -copy
        ## exit script with error code 1
        else
            echo "Unrecognized option \"$2\""
            usage
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
## if exactly one option specified
elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    ## if option is NOT a number
    ## check if option is -c or -copy
    if [[ ! "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
        ## if option is -c or -copy
        ## execute the command 
        if [[ "$1" == -c || "$1" == -copy ]]; then
            set - "$(length)"
            rand_string "$1" | pbcopy
            echo "Password copied to clipboard"
            exit
        ## if option is neither a number nor -c or -copy
        ## exit script with error code 1
        else
            echo "Unrecognized option \"$1\""
            usage
            exit 1
        fi
    ## if option is a number
    ## execute the command
    elif [[ "$1" =~ $re ]]; then
        rand_string "$1"
    fi
fi
```

This script takes two optional arguments:

- any whole number e.g.. `10`, `29`, `54` to determine the length of string
- `-c` or `-copy` to copy the string to the clipboard
- `-h` or `-help` to display the `usage` function

Any of the above arguments can be called from the `$1` or `$2` position. Any of these arguments may also be omitted.

Assuming the script is called `password` any of the following are **valid uses**:

`password`

`password 25`

`password -c`

`password 16 -copy`

`password -c 42`

`password -help`

But the script itself is a giant mess of `if` statements. It's long, messy and hard to read.

So my question is: How could this be written to take the same arguments shown in **valid uses** without using so many `if` statements?

I'm not asking anyone to rewrite my script. I'm just looking for some guidance to gain better understanding of how to do this correctly.

Comment: Did you try considering `getopts` for your requirement? it is tailor-made for this

Comment: Appreciate your detailed research, but still it is not _exactly_ clear what you want to do? Can you give a _minimal_ input and output needed for us to test on?

Comment: You think I should shorten the question?

Comment: Not exactly _shorten_ it, but make it easy for people to understand the code you are looking for. e.g. I want to do this, this way etc.

Comment: Or give us a list of all possible command-line inputs you want to achieve out of this

Comment: I think I have clarified what I'm trying to achieve. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Reading about `getopts` right now on the bash hackers wiki. Any other information resources are appreciated.

Comment: By the way, you should consider `--copy` rather than `-copy`.  `-copy` implies options c, o, p, and y are set.

Comment: @cdarke You mean with `getopts`? I just read it doesn't support long options.

Comment: Long options are non-standard, but commonly used.  `getopts` only supports standard options.   `-copy` would not work with `getopts`.

Comment: Yes, I read more about it last night. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/7680682#7680682) shows how it can be done. I see what you mean about `-copy` not working as it considers each letter a separate argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `getopts` then the simple way is to just `shift` the arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage(){
        echo "usage: $0 [n][-c]||[-h]" >&2
        exit 1
}

declare copy=
declare argument=

while [ "$1" ]; do
        case "$1" in
                -h|-help)
                        usage
                        ;;

                -c|-copy)
                        copy=1
                        ;;

                *)
                        [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || usage
                        argument="$1"
                        ;;
        esac
        shift
done

[ "$argument" ] || argument=$(length)

if [ "$copy" ]; then
        rand_string "$argument" | pbcopy
else
        rand_string "$argument"
fi
```

Comment: Wow that certainly simplified things. Thank you. :)